# "Subj + 打電話 + Obj" vs "Subj + 給 + Obj + 打電話"

Tags: grammar, difference

The dictionary entry of 打電話 that is given [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%89%93%E9%9B%BB%E8%A9%B1) says:

> **Verb**
>
> 1. to make a telephone call

Therefore, I would expect to be able to use it like this:

```
    我 晚上 要 打電話 媽媽
```

However, I found the following example [here](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Expressing_%22be_going_to%22_with_%22yao%22):

```
    我 晚上 要 給 媽媽 打電話
```

**Q:** are both versions valid? are they both the same?

---

Should 打電話 be read as a single unit or broken down into 打 電話 ? Is this a relevant issue?

The dictionary entry of 打 that is given [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%89%93#Chinese) lists:

> to send or call
>
> 打電報 / 打电报  ―  **dǎ** diànbào  ―  to **send** a telegraph
>
> 打電話 / 打电话  ―  **dǎ** diànhuà  ―  to **call** on the telephone
>
> 打手機 / 打手机  ―  **dǎ** shǒujī  ―  to **call** on the cellphone

Comment: This is a case of [transitivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_verb). The verb "to call" in English is transitive, but the verbal phrase 打电话 in Chinese is intransitive.

Comment: @Michaelyus thank you for pointing that out

Answer (score 6, accepted):

我 晚上 要 打电话 媽媽 : This is *invalid*.

In the phrase "打电话", "打" is the verb and "电话" is the object. And the "打" here is not a verb that can take two objects. So you must use: 我 晚上 要 **給 媽媽** 打電話

Comment: or 我 晚上 要  打電話 給 媽媽